# If else statment in FLEX text Area

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have an if else statement that change language Capabilitie EN to ENGLISH.

The thing is that its overwriting the other capabilities.

```
txtbox1.text = Capabilities.version + "\n" 
                + "\n" +Capabilities.isDebugger + "\n" +Capabilities.os
                + "\n" +Capabilities.playerType 

                    if(Capabilities.language == "en"){
                        txtbox1.text = "language: English";
                }
                else if (Capabilities.language.toLowerCase() == "sv"){
                    txtbox1.text = "language: swedish";
                }
                else {
                    txtbox1.text = "language: Other";
                }
                ;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var language : String = "";
if(Capabilities.language.toLowerCase() == "en")
    language = "language: English";
else if (Capabilities.language.toLowerCase() == "sv")
    language = "language: swedish";
else
    language = "language: Other";

txtbox1.text = Capabilities.version 
            + "\n" + Capabilities.isDebugger
            + "\n" + Capabilities.os
            + "\n" + Capabilities.playerType 
            + "\n" + language;
```

Comment: I had to change string language to var language than its started to work.
But I get a warning that language has no declaration. How can I solve that ? Thanks